# UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'cython_directives' when locally installing Cython package

Tags: python, pip, cython, setuptools, cythonize

I am using Cython version 0.29.26.
I have a python package with a Cython extension as follows:

**./setup.py:**

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext
import numpy as np


cython_directives = {'boundscheck': "False",
                     'cdivision': "True",
                     'wraparound': "False",
                     'language_level': "3"}

setup(name='debug_example',
      packages=find_packages(),
      cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
      ext_modules=[
          Extension('debug_example.example',
                    sources=['debug_example/example.pyx'],
                    language='c++',
                    include_dirs=[np.get_include()],
                    cython_directives=cython_directives,
                    )
      ]
      )
```

**./debug_example/example.pyx**

```py
cimport numpy as  np

cpdef int increment(int a):
    return a + 1
```

**`./debug_example/__init__.py`**:

```py
from .example import increment
```

When I compile it, I get a warning message about `cython_directives` being unknown (compilation works fine apart from that).
Output of `pip install -e . -v`:

```
(base) ➜  debug_cython pip install -e . -v
Using pip 21.2.4 from /home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
Obtaining file:///home/mm/tmp/debug_cython
    Running command python setup.py egg_info
    /home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/extension.py:131: UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'cython_directives'
```

what is the cause of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Extension` is from `setuptools` which has somewhat limited support for Cython: it automatically invokes `cythonize` for `*.pyx`-files but for more options one should use `cythonize` directly. That means the following for your `setup.py`:

```py
...
from Cython.Build import cythonize

...
extensions = [Extension('debug_example.example',
                    sources=['debug_example/example.pyx'],
                    language='c++',
                    include_dirs=[np.get_include()],
                    ),
              ]
...

setup(...
      ext_modules = cythonize(extensions, compiler_directives=cython_directives)
      ...
      )
```

I.e. `compiler_directives` can be passed to cythonize.

Comment: Oddly enough, doing this I get `ValueError: got unknown compilation option, please remove: cython_directives`

Comment: @P.Camilleri sorry, it is called `compiler_directives` and not `cython_directives`